# Google Analytics - Query all the metrics and dimensions names

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Is it possible to query all the possible metrics & dimensions with the Google Analytics API.

For example, with a HTTPS request I want a list with all possible metrics & dimensions like in here [Query Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/)

Comment: I just found out now that with an HTTP request to: https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/metadata/ga/columns you are able  to retrieve a list of all possible metrics & dimensions. What about the Goals? Is there any way to retrieve the goals defined for a specific website?

Comment: Yes the [Analytics Management API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/goals/list) can list all the user's goals. Also the query explorer is completely open source and it makes use of this [Javascript API Utils](https://github.com/googleanalytics/javascript-api-utils) library to get the user's goals and custom dimensions listed.